# Hibernate envers + hibernate-search : Reading audit information over Lucene/Elasticsearhc indexes

Tags: spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, hibernate-envers

I'm using hibernate-envers for audit purposes in an application. I'm also using hibernate-search in order to search/read the information of JPA entities in the application.

I was wondering if there's any kind of configuration/integration that can make hibernate-envers work with the audit enties/tables, over indexes too, in order to read with hibernate -search that information from the indexes.

I would like to avoid doing it "manually", for example, using envers event listeners in order to create/manipulate a new index manually for the audited entity, using a new JPA Entity modelling the Audit entity information including @Indexed annotation, fields etc.).

Ideally was wondering if there's support for envers/search integration out of the box, without custom development, to achieve storing all audit information in new _aud indexes.

Thanks in advance, any piece of advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not possible out of the box.

If it ever becomes possible, you won't benefit from all the Envers features such as "get me this entity at this revision". You will simply index all the revisions of each entity, and you will only be able to query (and retrieve) these revisions. That would be queries such as "get all revisions of the entity with id `1` where `name` contained `"some text"`.

Also, this will not remove the need for audit tables. The indexes will exist *in addition* to the audit tables.

That being said, I just gave it a try and we could make it possible in Hibernate Search 6 with just a few changes. If you're still interested, you can have a look there: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4238

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your comment and your time. I understand what you expose and seems totally reasonable. I was in need of complementary indexes, asuming audit table would woild still existing so your explanation seems a good fit for my needs. I'm also OK with the limitations of  the queries that would involve using Lucene/Elastic indexes instead of the AuditReader of envers. I will be following closely Hibernate Search 6, because if it gets released, even it will not be perfect, for me it will be nice to have.
Thanks you very much again.

Comment: @jarey FYI Hibernate Search 6 was already released at the end of last year: https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/ . I was suggesting to add this feature in a later minor release (e.g. 6.1). I'm not sure when we will come to it, though; but we gladly accept [contributions](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md) :)

Comment: @yrodiere what became of this?  Has it ever been added?

Comment: Jira issues are up to date, so the status you can see is correct: still open. Nobody contributed a fix yet.